# Improve Efficiency of Alog (Rotate Array to Left by n iterations)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance, big-o

I am solving a challenge to rotate array to left by `n` number of iterations.
Code is pretty much working but lags on very very huge input.
How to more improve efficiency

```
// Complete the rotLeft function below.
static int[] rotLeft(int[] a, int iterations) {

      for(int i=0;i<iterations;i++)
      {
         int[] temp=Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length);  
         temp=Arrays.copyOf(temp,a.length);
         temp[a.length-1]=a[0];
         a=temp;
      }


      return a;
}
```

Suggestions are welcome. 
Thanks

Comment: Reverse the whole array (in place). Then reverse between `0` and `iterations-1`. Then reverse between `iterations` and `a.length-1`. (Actually this is right shift, but same idea).

Answer (score 1):

Instead on shifting `iterations` you can calculate the final position directly.

```
finalIndex=(index-iterations+a.length)  % a.length
```

+a.length  is added to ensure that the `finalIndex` is always a not negattive value.

If you apply this to your algorithm, you get rid of the loop and do the whole thing in one step.

This reduced time complexity of the algorithm from **O(a.length*iterations)** to **O(a.length)**.

Comment: what is `index` here?

Comment: There's an even more efficient way :) (but I don't have time now)

Comment: @Ali Akram: `index` is the position of the element at the beginning.

Comment: @josejuan: Faster than *O(a.length)*? This seams to be impossible, if we need an array at the end where all elements have changed.

Comment: @MrSmith42 - not faster than O(a.length), but faster constant time. If rotating a large array with a large iteration value, there will be a lot of cache misses. My answer shows an inplace (no second array) solution that does swaps, which is more writes, but these are done in sequential sequences, regardless of iterations, which is more cache friendly.

Answer (score 1):

There are few flaws in the code.

- First, you do redundant work - if `iterations > a.length` - then after a.length iterations the array just returns back to itself.
- Second, each iteration creates a whole new copy of the array!
- Third, the new location of each element in the array can be predetermined by looking only on the array length, the number of iterations required, and the index of this element, no need to repeatidly go over iterations.

When taking these into considerations, this can boil down to something in the form of:

```
 static int[] rotLeftEfficient(int[] a, int iterations) {
    iterations = iterations % a.length;
    int[] b = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        int newIndex = (i - iterations + a.length) % a.length;
        b[newIndex] = a[i];
    }
    return b;
}
```

This boils down to `O(n)` solution - where `n` is the number of elements in the array, with decent constants as well.

Comment: @josejuan Why should I think otherwise?  It is not restricted anywhere, and as an interviewer, this is one edge case I would accept an interviewee to check if I use this question in an interview.

Comment: @josejuan I do not follow. This solution works for all inputs, even without the pre condition that `iterations > a.length` with minor cost (1 extra modolus operation), I really don't see the downside of using it.

Comment: I tested the code using a 2^28 = 268,435,456 element array. It took almost 0.3 seconds to allocate b[], so I did that in main() and passed b as a parameter to the rotate function. With this change, the rotate function takes around 0.65 seconds, faster than my answer's worst case (rotate 1) 0.85 seconds, slower than my answer's best cases 0.17 seconds. I don't know if Java optimizes % a.length to use multiply by inverse instead of using divide. The % could be replaced with an if / subtract sequence to speed things up. The allocate time for a large array of 0.3 seconds makes it overall slower.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rotate in place (doesn't use a second array), with O(a.length) time complexity. On my system (Intel 3770K 3.5ghz), it can rotate a 2^28 = 268,435,456 element array in .17 (rotate 76) to .85 seconds (rotate 1). The swaps are done in sequential access sequences, which is cache friendly.

```
    // rotate in place
    public static void rolip(int[] a, int r){
        r = r % a.length;
        if(r == 0)
            return;
        int t;
        int n = a.length - r;
        int i = 0;
        int j;
        while(true){
            if(r <= n){                     // shift left r places
                for(j = i+r; i < j; i++){
                    t = a[i];               //  swap(a[i], a[i+r])
                    a[i] = a[i+r];
                    a[i+r] = t;
                }
                n -= r;
                if(n == 0)
                    break;
            } else {                        // shift right n places
                i += r;
                for(j = i+n; i < j; i++){
                    t = a[i];               //  swap(a[i], a[i-n])
                    a[i] = a[i-n];
                    a[i-n] = t;
                }
                i -= n+r;
                r -= n;
                if(r == 0)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Simple rotate using a second array. On my system (Intel 3770K 3.5ghz), it can rotate a 2^28 = 268,435,456 element array in .11 to .50 seconds.

```
    public static void rol(int[] a, int r){
        r = r % a.length;
        if(r == 0)
            return;
        int n = a.length - r;
        int i;
        int j;
        if(r <= n){                         // if left rotate
            int[] b = new int[r];           //  save elements
            for(j = 0; j < r; j++)
                b[j] = a[j];
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++)          //  shift elements
                a[i] = a[j++];
            for(j = 0; j < r; j++)          //  copy saved elements
                a[i++] = b[j];
        } else {                            // else right rotate
            int[] b = new int[n];           //  save elements
            i = 0;
            for(j = r; j < a.length; j++)
                b[i++] = a[j];
            i = j-1;                        //  shift elements
            for(j = i-n; j >= 0; j--)
                a[i--] = a[j];
            for(j = 0; j < n; j++)          //  copy saved elements
                a[j] = b[j];
        }
    }
```

Comment: for low `min(r, a.length - r)` values the performance is very poor, the penalty is proportional to `1 / min(r, a.length - r)` (so, the penalty no matter for values grater than 10~100 but is not acceptable for lowers)

Comment: @josejuan - this type of in place merge is often used for in place (no second array) merge sorts, such as [block merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_sort) .

Comment: "It has to be very small" 30% is not very small (same `rolip` with different `r`), in fact, if you use an intermediate `k = i + r; ... a[i]=a[k]; ...i++, k++` you get a (light) better perf. Probably you can unroll loops to avoid that (30%) overhead. Anyway I think your solution is the best (the +1 is mine ;)

Comment: @josejuan - I added a simple rotate using a second array (size is min(r , a.length-r)). This should be faster than the in place rotate, for most cases. There is some overhead for allocating a large second array. I also get some cache conflicts with certain patterns (array size power of 2, rotate = (1/2 array size) + or - 1.

Comment: Good approach but, once you create the intermediate array, why not `int i = a.length - (r % a.length); System.arraycopy(b, i, a, 0, a.length - i); System.arraycopy(b, 0, a, a.length - i, i);`?

Comment: @josejuan - Is the array copy that much faster? I was thinking Java compiler would convert the loop into arraycopy(), similar to the way that C / C++ compilers converting a similar loop into memcpy().

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it for every iteration. Instead you can create a formula to figure out where every element would go.

For example, let's say that the size of your array is n.

Then, if you need to move your array to the left by 1 iteration, then an element at position p would be at (p + 1) % n position.

For i iterations, every element would be at (p + i) % n location. So, a loop for every iteration is not needed.

```
   static int[] rotLeft(int[] a, int iterations) {
        int[] answer = new int[a.length];
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            answer[i] = a[(i - iterations + a.length) % (a.length)];
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

Comment: This does not fulfill all use case , but yes few only.

Comment: @AliAkram which use case would it not fulfill?

Answer (score -2):

What about this:

```
    static int leftRotate(int arr[], int iterations, 
                                     int k) 
    { 
        /* To get the starting point of  
        rotated array */
        int mod = k % iterations; 

        // Prints the rotated array from  
        // start position 
        for(int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) 
        System.out.print(arr[(i + mod) % iterations] 
                          + " ");  

        System.out.println(); 
    } 

leftRotate(arr, iterations, arr.length);
```

Ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-left-rotation-array/